# Were high quality reproductions of the Star Wars matte paintings ever produced?

Tags: star-wars

For everyone who does not know yet: The settings in the original *Star Wars* movies were created with amazing matte paintings. You can see some of them [here](https://gizmodo.com/the-amazing-matte-paintings-from-star-wars-and-their-cr-1680372651).

Aside from the stunning technical aspects these paintings are magnificent pieces of art on its own. As you can see in the link these paintings are quite large. I am craving for some of them as wallpaper for my desktop or even wall, but all images I can find on the web are of low quality.

Were high quality photocopies or something similar ever fashioned from these paintings that can be acquired in some reasonable way?

Comment: FWIW if this is considered a shopping question, it would probably be on topic per the [ruling on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/501/58193).

Comment: Alright, that is nice to hear! I really have not been able to find anything, free _or_ in a shop.

Comment: Maybe not the mattes themselves, but a fair few of Ralph Macquarie's concept art has been sold as prints - I found a pack of about a dozen or so in a second-hand store a few years back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While primarily focused on concept art, the ["*Art of Star Wars*" series of books](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Art_of_Star_Wars_Books?so=search) includes many of the matte paintings used in the Original Trilogy:

- *The Art of Star Wars* (A New Hope)

  - Tatooine orbit (p10)
  - Mos Eisley overlook (p70)
  - Alderaan orbit (p77)
  - Death Star tractor beam control (p83)
  - Death Star chasm (p84-85)
  - Yavin orbit (p102-103)
- *The Art of The Empire Strikes Back*

  - Hoth landscape (p14-15)
  - Star Destroyer bridge (p76-77)
  - Dagobah orbit (p82-83)
  - Dagobah swamp (p89)
  - Asteroid orbit (p115)
  - Bespin landing platform (p122-123)
  - Bespin skyline (p128-129)
  - Bespin sunset (p134-135)
  - Bespin Slave I (p144)
  - Bespin central shaft (p156-159)
- *The Art of Return of the Jedi*

  - Death Star II hangars (p5)
  - Death Star II docking bay (p6-9)
  - Jabba's palace exterior (p10-11)
  - Rebel hangar (p62-63)
  - Ewok village (p86, 90, 144-145)
  - Endor landscape (p95)
  - Endor landing platform (p97-100)
  - Death Star II shaft (p136-137)

I also found a [post on the blog "Matte Shot"](http://nzpetesmatteshot.blogspot.com/2022/03/industrial-light-magic-matte-art-part.html) containing photos or scans of many of the matte paintings used in the films. While the quality of these vary and the provenance is unclear, many are at 1920x1080 resolution or higher and may work as desktop wallpaper.